How to Suppress MISSING_MESSAGE Errors in next-intl in Next.js App?
I'm developing a Next.js app using the next-intl package for locale handling, and I am loading the locale messages from an external server. Most of the messages do not exist in my local development environment, which results in numerous MISSING_MESSAGE errors cluttering the console and making it hard to debug.
I am using next-intl version 3.25.1 and the following code is from i18n/request.js
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';
import { routing } from './routing';

export default getRequestConfig(async ({ requestLocale }) => {
    let locale = await requestLocale;

    if (!locale || !routing.locales.includes(locale)) {
        locale = routing.defaultLocale;
    }

    websiteUrl = websiteUrl.replace(process.env.WEBSITE_CONFIG_URL);

    const websiteResponse = await fetch(websiteUrl);
    const websiteResult = await websiteResponse.json();
    const messages = websiteResult.content;
    
    return { 
        locale, 
        messages,
        onError(error) {
            return;
        },
        getMessageFallback({error, key}) {
            return key;
        }
    };
});

This code is called because my translation are loaded from the server, I can see them in the rendering.
Even though I have provided the onError function to suppress errors, the MISSING_MESSAGE errors still appear in the logs. How can I effectively prevent these specific errors from appearing in my console (terminal and browser) during development?
What I've tried:

Adding an onError handler that returns undefined to suppress logs.
Setting a getMessageFallback that returns the key as a fallback message.
Add onError on NextIntlClientProvider

Expected Outcome:
I would like a way to filter out or suppress the MISSING_MESSAGE logs while retaining the ability to debug other important messages.
The onError on NextIntlClientProvider generates error Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props and as I am charging server messages, this code can lot be executed on client.
Any suggestions or examples on how to solve this issue would be appreciated!

I found a solution,
Looks like I had to divide the layout in two parts, one handeled by both the server and the client app/[locale]/layout.jsx
import Head from "next/head";
import { getMessages, setRequestLocale } from 'next-intl/server'
import {notFound} from 'next/navigation';
import {routing} from '../../i18n/routing'
import ClientLayout from "../components/clientLayout";

export default async function RootLayout({ children, params }) {

  const { locale } = await params
  const messages = await getMessages();

  if (!routing.locales.includes(locale)) {
    notFound();
  }

  setRequestLocale(locale);

  return (
    <html lang={locale} >
      <Head>
        <title>Amazing title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Description 1234" />
        <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
      </Head>

      <body>
        <ClientLayout locale={locale} messages={messages} >
          {children}
        </ClientLayout>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return routing.locales.map((locale) => ({locale}));
}

And then another one only for client
'use client'
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from "next-intl";
import Context from "../context";

export default function ClientLayout({ children, locale, messages }) {

    function onError(error) {
        if (error.code === 'MISSING_MESSAGE') return;
        console.error(error)
    }

    return (
        <Context>
            <NextIntlClientProvider
                locale={locale}
                messages={messages}
                timeZone='Europe/Paris'
                onError={onError}
            >
                {children}
            </NextIntlClientProvider>
        </Context>
    )
}

